# Что не так с моей командой (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ALTER TABLE project_list
    -> CHANGE COLUMN number proj_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> ADD PRIMARY KEY ('proj_id');
```

Ошибка

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''proj_id')' at line 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй
`-> ADD PRIMARY KEY (proj_id);`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь